# I can't run the below script in custom master page?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, csom, custom-masterpage, jsom

While running the below script,It's shows the

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined,

I researched about the error, I found the root cause of the error `SP.js` file is not loaded.How to solve that issues in the below script?

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
var userProfileProperties;

function getUserProperties() {


    var targetUser = "SomeDomain\\SomeUserName";

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "PictureURL"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
    clientContext,
    targetUser,
    profilePropertyNames);

    userProfileProperties =peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}


function onRequestSuccess()
 {
    document.getElementById("profilelink").href = userProfileProperties[1];;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = userProfileProperties[0];
    if (userProfileProperties[1]!== null) {
        document.getElementById("Userprofileimage").src = userProfileProperties[1];
    }
}


function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("Userprofileimage ").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    //Do not change the order, scripts should load by order.  
     $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                   function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.UserProfiles.js", getUserProperties);
              });
          });
           });
// **add your code**
</script>
```

Then add your code at `// **add your code**`

**Note :**  loading scripts in the order is very important.

For more Details Check [Show Logged in User Profile Picture & Display First Name using CSOM (SharePoint 2010/2013)](http://www.sptechlearn.com/2013/07/show-logged-in-user-profile-picture-display-first-name-using-csom-sharepoint-20102013.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace **SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');** with the following line

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js', 'SP.UserProfiles', getUserProperties);
});
```

Please check, this should work for you. Because you have to make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before code runs, otherwise you get "ClientContext" as undefined.